# Magento 2 PWA Get product reviews

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio

How I query magento 2 to get the ratings for the particular product. Any one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are familiar with the graphQL [queries](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/index.html) that need  to be used to retrieve data, and how Magento includes them using custom gql.js files (e.g. [productFullDetail.gql.js](https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/blob/develop/packages/peregrine/lib/talons/ProductFullDetail/productFullDetail.gql.js)), you could use the following query to retrieve product reviews:

```
query getProductReviews(
        $sku: String!
    ) {
        products(filter: { sku: { eq: $sku } }) {
            items {
                review_count
                rating_summary
                reviews {
                    items {
                        average_rating
                        summary
                        text
                        created_at
                        nickname
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and just use the **sku** [variable](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) to switch between products:

```
{  
  "sku": "24-MB01"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.Its work fine

Comment: How do we get the review filter by store id and except reviews that has the status of pending.

Comment: You cannot do that out-of-the-box with Magento's products query, because you can only filter using product attributes (not review attributes). So you would need a custom implementation with a custom resolver where you can input a product sku and the 'pending' status for example.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Please following API for getting product reviews.

```
{
    reviewsList(
        product_id:57573,
        pageSize:10,
        currentPage:1
    ){
        items {
            review_id
            title
            rating_summary
            images
            detail
            nickname
            created_at
        }
    }
}
```